# How to open application on a specific display in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors

I am using dual monitors and whenever one of my application opens a new window, it is always created in my secondary display instead of my primary display. I've attempted solutions involving Auto Move Windows and CompizConfig, but they all don't work in Ubuntu 20.04. Has anyone found a work around for this issue?

Comment: Anything about "compiz" is certainly outdated.

Comment: Compiz is still usable on Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/267099

Comment: In Gnome Tweaks, there is an option "Center new windows" on the Windows tab. I suggest you try that option. Maybe this could help consistently opening applications on the same (hopefully the primary) display. Now, it is the "smart" setting that sometimes decides to open a new window on the other display.

Answer (score 0):

My secondary monitor is on top of the main monitor and Ubuntu 20.04 always opened the applications in the secondary one. Many users recommended that I have to move the secondary monitor to right side and/or try to use different applications. None of them worked for me.

@vanadium's answer seems working for me:

```
Tweaks > Windows > Center New Windows
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a game like bzflag